# Prevent check-ins and restrict merges for TFS branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

In my environment we have Dev, Main and Production branches. We also have Business and Architecture teams. What I would like to achieve is the following:

1. Both teams can Contribute to Dev
2. The Business team can only read Main and Production
3. The Architecture team can only merge into Main and Production

Currently, both teams are members of the Contributors group on the Team Project.

---

Final Solution:

1. Created a Group called Promo Officers at the collection level
2. Added the Architecture team to the new group
3. Added the Promo group to the permissions at the collection level (in Source Control Explorer right-click the collection, select properties and click permissions
4. Gave Promo Officers Read, Check Out, Check In, Label, Admin Labels, Merge and Manage Branch permissions
5. Turned off Inherit Security for the Main and Production branches.
6. Set the permissions for Contributors to just Read.

NB: You can't deny the unwanted permissions for Contributors because if a user is both in Contributors and Promo Officers, then the deny takes precedence and they won't have the correct permissions. Secondly, I wasn't able to achieve my goal of only allowing merges to Main and Production as you need Check In and Check out permissions to do merges.

Comment: this worked ... I upvoted and this is best answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you right-click a folder in Source Control Explorer and go to Properties -> Security you can manage permissions right down to the folder/branch level.

Comment: Hey Dylan! Unfortunately I need a lot more guidance. I know I can set the permissions in the properties, but I'm not clear on what to set them to. Should I remove the Contributors group and add my two custom groups directly?

Comment: I would leave the Dev folder with the defaults, but I would edit the MAIN and PRODUCTION folders to remove Contributors ability to write/check-in (but leave read), and explicitly add the Architecture group to allow them to Merge/Check-In etc.